# django -Working with user data in views

Tags: django

I'm trying to attach user data to be saved with a form.  However I'm getting a not-null constraint error, which I don't understand as there doesn't seem to be a null constraint.
"null value in column "user_id" violates not-null constraint"

View:

```
class SupplierOnlineAccountView(CreateView):
    form_class = SupplierOnlineAccountForm
    template_name = 'standard_form.html'
    success_url = '../contacting'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated():
            form.instance.user = self.request.user
        else:
            form.instance.temp_user = self.request.session.session_key
        form.instance.service_type = self.request.session['service_type']
        form.instance.online_account = self.request.session['online_account']
        username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
        password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
        self.object = form.save()
        api(username, password, self.object)

        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Form:

```
class SupplierOnlineAccountForm(forms.ModelForm):
    supplier_list = Supplier.objects.all()
    supplier = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=supplier_list, empty_label=None, to_field_name='name')

    class Meta:
        model = SupplierAccount
        fields = ['supplier', 'username', 'password']
```

Model:

```
class SupplierAccount(models.Model):
    service_type = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True)
    online_account = models.BooleanField()
    supplier = models.ForeignKey(Supplier)
    tariff = models.ForeignKey(Tariff, null=True)
    tariff_prices = models.ForeignKey(TariffPrices, null=True)
    p_usage = models.ForeignKey(PowerUsage, null=True)
    g_usage = models.ForeignKey(GasUsage, null=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(EUser)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.service_type


class EUser(models.Model):
    address = models.ForeignKey(Address, null=True)
    temp_user = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, null=True, default=None)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user)
```

The Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/B/.virtualenvs/switcher5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.IntegrityError: null value in column "user_id" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (6, t, ytest@yahoo.com, testpass, null, null, 2, null, null, null, D).

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/B/.virtualenvs/switcher5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 149, in get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/Users/B/.virtualenvs/switcher5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 147, in get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/contextlib.py", line 30, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwds)
  File "/Users/B/.virtualenvs/switcher5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 68, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/B/.virtualenvs/switcher5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 88, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/B/.virtualenvs/switcher5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py", line 256, in post
    return super(BaseCreateView, self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/B/.virtualenvs/switcher5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py", line 222, in post
    return self.form_valid(form)
  File "/Users/B/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/PycharmProjects/switcher5/euser/views.py", line 58, in form_valid
    self.object = form.save()
  File "/Users/B/.virtualenvs/switcher5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/forms/models.py", line 451, in save
    self.instance.save()
  File "/Users/B/.virtualenvs/switcher5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 700, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "/Users/B/.virtualenvs/switcher5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 728, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
  File "/Users/B/.virtualenvs/switcher5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 812, in _save_table
    result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
  File "/Users/B/.virtualenvs/switcher5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 851, in _do_insert
    using=using, raw=raw)
  File "/Users/B/.virtualenvs/switcher5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 122, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/B/.virtualenvs/switcher5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1039, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
  File "/Users/B/.virtualenvs/switcher5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1060, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/B/.virtualenvs/switcher5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/debug_toolbar/panels/sql/tracking.py", line 159, in execute
    return self._record(self.cursor.execute, sql, params)
  File "/Users/B/.virtualenvs/switcher5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/debug_toolbar/panels/sql/tracking.py", line 101, in _record
    return method(sql, params)
  File "/Users/B/.virtualenvs/switcher5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 79, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/B/.virtualenvs/switcher5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/B/.virtualenvs/switcher5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 95, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/Users/B/.virtualenvs/switcher5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/Users/B/.virtualenvs/switcher5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: null value in column "user_id" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (6, t, ytest@yahoo.com, testpass, null, null, 2, null, null, null, D).
```

Comment: If you're getting an error you need to show it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your view doesn't require a user when saving the form, but the model does, since the ForeignKey to EUser has no null=True. If you want to permit the case where the user is not authenticated, you need to set that attribute on the `user` foreignkey.

Comment: Thanks, currently I can't get this to work either for authenticated users or to save data attached to a session/temp_user.  If I try to save for an authenticated user, I get a `RelatedObjectDoesNotExist SupplierAccount has no user error` presumably because the model doesn't have a direct foreignkey to User but instead via EUser.  How do I save and attach the form to an instance of EUser either authenticated or not authenticated /temp_user.

Comment: Solved this error by attaching the other models directly to the User model instead of via EUser